# Laravel events behind load balancer - how to make the event visible to all the servers in the autoscale group

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs, laravel

I have an application running Laravel 6.1. There are clients which connect to it via laravel websockets and listen for events. I have an external service which sends post requests to this server which will then raise an event, and the websocket clients see it. I am in the dev stage, and it's not been deployed yet, this is what I'm currently researching. I use Docker, so there's an nginx container, a php container, and a Mysql container(in production, the containers will use RDS though)

This works fine in development, but the plan is to deploy in ECS, with Elastic Beanstalk, as it enables multiple containers per EC2 instance. I was planning on having these instances auto scale with a load balancer, so my question is **how can I make the incoming events be raised and visible on all the servers?** For example, the post request may hit one instance and the clients connected to that instance would see that the event was raised, but the clients connected to another instance will not see the raised event. Is this accurate? I'd imagine the events will have to be sent to some kind of "queue" which is monitored by all instances, but not sure how to implement that with Laravel or if there's a simpler faster way.

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS SNS for notifications, to be monitored by all instances